# CoreWCF vs Classic WCF windows authentication failure

Tags: authentication, wcf, corewcf

I have this scenario:

- Microsoft Dynamics AX WCF service running in two different environments: **production** and **test**; in production the service has two instances, balanced with DNS, in test only one instance
- Access to the service is granted via integrated Windows authentication
- Every instance of the WCF service runs via Windows Services (so it's not hosted in IIS)
- **WCF** client library in *Net Framework 4.8* (I will call it *old*)
- **CoreWCF** client library in *Net 6* (I will call it *new*)
- Two different testing programs (*old* and *new*), both running within a Windows session started by the same authorized user (same user, same AD domain)

Testing the two libraries I have different behaviors:

- *Old* works always both versus production and test
- *New* work versus production, but not test

Error thrown by the testing application is the following:

`---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090322): Target Principal Name is incorrect.`

Any suggestion on how to debug this situation?

Comment: Is there still a problem with the test environment also setting up two instances?

Comment: It's not simple to clone a Dynamics AX testing instance; maybe I can replicate a NLB logic, but with only one instance, adding the intermediate hop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear to me what's really happening here, but I solved the problem **adding a CNAME record to the DNS server**, pointing to the MS Dynamix AX test server.
I've diffusely *black box tested* production and testing environment.

**Net Core**:

- Tested direct access to PROD and TEST servers by their names (A records) => KO both with *Auth failure*
- Tested access to PROD and TEST servers via CNAME records => OK
- Tested access to PROD server through NLB => OK

**Classic Net Framework**:

- Always OK

So, based on these tests, I can state the following:

- NLB is not influent
- If you use CoreWCF access to the AD security protected service through a CNAME

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have used **SPN**. Each instance in the transport must have a corresponding **SPN**. So when you only have one instance, it can cause this problem.

The value attribute of SPN in 'Microsoft Learning' is described as: The name by which a client uniquely identifies an instance of a service. If you install multiple instances of a service on computers throughout a forest, each instance must have its own SPN. A given service instance can have multiple SPNs if there are multiple names that clients might use for authentication.

I searched various forums for posts on this issue, and they all thought it was related to SPN. In fact, when I read the docs I thought the problem should be here. I think your test direction can be placed here.

[WCF SPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/serviceprincipalname) [SPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/extendedprotection/spn)

Comment: Your commenst and suggestions guided me to a solution. I've not understood well why, but now it works. I posted a solution below, where I explain the tests and the results. Thank you.